# Pushing data to an array in already existing object with axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

i have a object which looks like this:

```
 {
      "title": "675756",
      "release_date": "2022-01-16",
      "series": "Better Call Saul",
      "img": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/03/Walter_White_S5B.png", 
      "characters": [],
      "id": 1
    }
```

to an `characters` array i want to add the `id` of characters.
I do it by `form` and then i `handle submit` like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log("dodano aktora do filmu!");
    console.log(values);
    addActorToMovie(values);

    history.goBack();
  };
```

the `addActorToMovie` action:

```
export const addActorToMovie = (resp) => ({
  type: types.ADD_CHAR_TO_MOVIE,
  payload: resp,
});
```

and the reducer:

```
 case types.ADD_CHAR_TO_MOVIE:
      console.log(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        ...state.episodes.map(function (item) {
          return item.id === action.payload.episodeId
            ? {
                id: item.id,
                title: item.title,
                release_date: item.release_date,
                series: item.series,
                img: item.img,
                characters: [...item.characters, action.payload.actor],
              }
            : { ...item };
        }),
      };
```

It all works, but the problem is that i dont want to do it loccaly. Im using an `database` with json-server, and I want to do an `Axios Request` so that it would add a data to the `database`.
And i don't know how to do this, when i use `axios.post` it adds an object to my `episodes` array, if im using `axios.put` it changes an object. Is there any possibility to push the data to an array as i do it with the code above, but with axios so that it would be added to `database`?

My approach looked like this:

```
export const addActorToMovieAxios = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:3000/episodes/`,
        value
      );
      console.log(response);
      dispatch(addActorToMovie(response.data));
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
  };
};
```

but as I said this does add a new object to an array.....

```
"episodes": [
    {
      "title": "675756",
      "release_date": "2022-01-16",
      "series": "Better Call Saul",
      "img": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/03/Walter_White_S5B.png",
      "characters": [],
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "episodeId": 1,
      "actor": "1",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Is this even possible to make?

Comment: You need to have backend to talk to the db, so the actual add to db would be handled on your POST http://localhost:3000/episodes/ endpoint.
Axios can't modify database by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

So just to be clear I understand your question, you have an object that already exists in your DB, and you want to push something onto the 'characters' array in that existing object, without creating a new object, correct?

To do this, I would use Mongo for your DB and define two Mongoose Schemas, one for the existing object (let's call it TVShow) and one for the Characters within that object. Your two Schemas will look like this:

TVShowModel.js:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CharacterModel = require('./CharacterModel')

const TVShowScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    release_date: {
        type: Date,
    },
    series: {
        type: String,
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
    },
    characters:[
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'Student'
        },               
    ],
    examQuestions: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'CharacterModel'
        }
    ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('TVShowModel', TVShowScheme )
```

CharacterModel.js:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CharacterModel= new mongoose.Schema({
    characterName: {
        type: String,
    },
    actorName: {
        type: String,
    },       
}) // add any other fields you want here

module.exports = mongoose.model('CharacterModel', CharactModelScheme )
```

Then, create your Axios post request. Make sure you send when you send the 'value' variable to your server, it contains the id (or perhaps the unique title) of the object you'll be 'pushing' to. Push won't work in axios/react, so we'll use the 'spread' opperator instead.

Your router will look like this:

```js
const CharacterModel= require ('../models/CharacterModel');
const TVShowModel= require ('../models/TVShowModel');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/episodes', async function(req,res){
try{

    const tvshow = await TVShowModel.find({title: req.body.title})        
    // edit as needed

    console.log("FOUND TV Show: "+tvshow )

    const characterName= req.body.characterName
    const actorName = req.body.actorName 

    const newCharacter = new CharacterModel({
        characterName,
        actorName,
    })

    console.log("new character created: "+newCharacter)

    tvshow[0].CharacterModel = [...tvshow[0].CharacterModel,newCharacter];       
    
   
    await tvshow[0].save()
     .then(()=>res.json('New Character Added to DB'))
     .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))

} catch(e){
    console.log(e)        
}
})
```

Hope this was clear!